# Calling generics method argument in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun <T> doSum(a: T, b: T) : T {
    val result : Number = when {
        a is Int && b is Int -> a + b
        a is Long && b is Long -> a + b
        a is Float && b is Float -> a + b
        a is Double && b is Double -> a + b
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException() 

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return result as T
}

fun <T: Number> doOperation(a: T, b: T, operationToPerform: (T, T) -> T ) {
    println(operationToPerform(a, b))
}
```

I have the method doOperations that takes a generics function as a parameter that I intend to run on the other 2 parameters passed. 
However, invoking the same in main as :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    doOperation (2, 3, doSum)
}
```

is returning errors like:

```
Error:(15, 24) Kotlin: Function invocation 'doSum(...)' expected
Error:(15, 24) Kotlin: No value passed for parameter 'a'
Error:(15, 24) Kotlin: No value passed for parameter 'b'
```

Any suggestions on the way to call doOperation with doSum()?

(& changing < T > doSum to < T: Number > doSum throws up one more error: 
Error:(15, 24) Kotlin: Type parameter bound for T in fun  doSum(a: T, b: T): T
 is not satisfied: inferred type (Int, Int) -> Int is not a subtype of Number)

Comment: Do you have a copy/paste error in your original post or are you missing some brackets?  It looks like you're not closing the `doSum` method (or the `when` call inside of it)

Comment: Also, try sending in `doSum(...)` like this: `doOperation (2, 3, ::doSum)`

Comment: Thanks @MFazio23. That was a copy paste error. I found the issue to be not using :: for high order function.

Comment: And make sure you return something out of `doSum(...)`.  You can always return the `when` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MFazio23, I updated the question with missed lines having return and closing bracket. Do you want to post that statement doOperation (2, 3, ::doSum) as an answer - I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that comes in here at a later date, the fix here was to send in the `doSum(...)` method like this:

```
doOperation (2, 3, ::doSum)
```

Adding the `::` before `doSum(...)` allows you to reference a top-level, local, or member function.

More info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types